# Do versions below 3.x of OpenLayers still work?

Tags: callback, timeout, openlayers

Versions below version 3 of OpenLayers still work?

I have a tracking system that still uses this API to just plot the point on the map, but it is showing slowness in requests.
I started experiencing slowdowns on my system, which uses a version below 3, this one: https://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js
Tx

Comment: We have an application which still use OL V2